# Performance Issue: Time Load to View Increasing Over Time

Tags: ios, performance, memory-leaks, profiling

I am developing an iOS app using UINavigationController. I am experiencing a performance issue where the amount of time it takes to load new views increases by about 0.1 seconds each time the view is loaded. I am hoping that someone can provide with general advice on how to approach this problem.

I included the profiling data below. There does not seem to be any unbounded growth or memory leaks.

Some more information on the app: It has fair number of views (upwards of 20) and has fairly complex tableviews with many different custom cells. I use a base viewcontroller which contains all of the tableview and navigation code which I subclass for each individual view controller.

[image]
[image]

Here is an example code which loads a view that exhibits this performance issue:

```
-(IBAction)evaluateTapped:(id)sender
{

  NSArray *arrayOfPropertiesToLoad =    [self.sharedStore requestAnArrayOfObjectsWithEntityDescription:@"Property" forWhichAttribute:@"isEvaluated" isEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

NSArray *sortedArray =    [[OzStore sharedStore] sortArray:arrayOfPropertiesToLoad withKey:@"id" ascending:NO];
    NSMutableArray *mutSortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];

    OzEvaluatePropertyListViewController *propertyList = [[OzEvaluatePropertyListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil withSortedDataArray:mutSortedArray useCellClass:@"OzPropertyCell" withUnit:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:propertyList animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you try time profiling to see what is happening during the extra time? Also, show some code around the view creation - are there any loops there?

Comment: In addition to Time Profiler instrument you can place CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() calls at various points in code and see where the most time is spent

Comment: I used the time profiling and seems that all of the top time consuming methods increase in time. The top method is cellForRowAtIndexPath. I have custom UITableViewCells with a lot of subviews and I think that is hurting my performance. However, that alone does not explain why my performance worsens over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! After doing a lot of extensive testing I realized that the methods leading up to `viewWillAppear` were timed about the same each time a view controller was loaded and popped. However, the time between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` increased by about 0.1 seconds every time a view was loaded. Profiling using timer showed that layoutSubViews was taking an increasing amount of time.

It turns out I had the following code in the parent `viewDidLoad` method of all of my view controllers:

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluecool"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


     NSDictionary *a = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:20], NSFontAttributeName,
     [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:a];
```

Everytime the `viewDidLoad` was called it must have been adding an additional layer of background image to the navigation bar. I simply moved this code to the appDelegate so it was only called and the problem was solved.